# swift get class properties with name stored in another variable

Tags: swift, properties

If I have an array "properties" with the properties of my class

```
public class Circle {
  private var properties = ["radius", "diameter", "area", "perimeter"]

  public var radius: Double = 0.0
  public var diameter: Double = 0.0
  public var area: Double = 0.0
  public var perimeter: Double = 0.0
```

is there any way to get the properties' values using the array..?

I tried:

```
    public var description: String {
      var str = description()
      for label in properties {
          let value = label
          str +=  label + "\t\(self.(value))\n"
    }
    return str
}
```

but it doesn't work, how can I get the properties, using their names stored in another variable like "value"?

Comment: Your code should work. Remove `self.` from this code: `str +=  label + "\t\(self.(value))\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can update the class to conform to NSObject, you can use the `valueForKey:` method

```
public class Circle: NSObject {
  private var properties = ["radius", "diameter", "area", "perimeter"]

  public var radius: Double = 0.0
  public var diameter: Double = 0.0
  public var area: Double = 0.0
  public var perimeter: Double = 0.0

  public var description: String {
    var str = description()
    for label in properties {
        let value = value(forKey: label)
        str +=  label + "\t\(label): \(value)\n"
  }
  return str
}
```